# How to properly structure REST-API endpoints

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-restcontroller

im quite new with REST-API.

i want to have something like this

```
POST http://localhost/posts/ <--- PostsController.java
GET http://localhost/posts/{id} <--- PostsController.java
POST http://localhost/posts/{id}/comments <--- CommentsController.java
GET http://localhost/posts/{id}/comments <--- CommentsController.java
GET http://localhost/posts/{id}/comments/{id} <--- CommentsController.java
```

Where the following controllers handle `/posts` and another controller handler `/comments`

**PostsController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/posts")
public class PostsController {
   // something
}
```

**CommentsController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/comments")
public class CommentsController {
 //do something
}
```

How do i maintain the above url whilst having different controllers to handle it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll share my expreience here.
When I work with Rest controllers, I always try to understand what is the "core" entity - a notion we deal with and what are just criterias for queries. Usually the "core" entity appears right after the context path.

Note that this doesn't really depend on  an actual implementation at the level of database.

So it looks like all the cases are actually about the "post" entity that's why you've put it in the first place (in the case of comments by post, you didn't opt for something like this `http://localhost/comments?post=123` and that's ok, it just means that post is your "main" entity to serve.

In this case I think all the operations can be done in `PostsController`.

Now an important side-note about controllers in Spring / SpringBoot.
People tend to put business logic in these controllers and I believe its a mistake. Controllers should not contain any real logic, maybe some light input transformations / validations but that's it. Leave a real work to "Services" not to controllers, keep controllers to be an entry point for your backend. Now why I'm stating this? Because controllers, if written in this way are really small classes, so you won't get a one "giant" class that handles all, which, I believe, might be an argument for separation to different controllers.

Ok, so what is comments in this case? It depends on how you think about it, but as you wrote in end-points list, is a property of post (something that belongs to the post/ always associated with the post), so its a "Criteria of search": give me a post with comments, give me only a post without comments, give me a post that has comments only from today and yesterday, the point is that you always query for "post", not for comments.

From the purely technical standpoint, the `@RequestMapping` in spring boot when put on controller class says that only `/post` can be queried by this controller.
You can also set different values on `@GetMapping/@PostMapping` annotations but that's 
it. If should be flexible enough to design the level of rest controllers.

Comment: Agree, i might be over thinking of over simplifying classes though. My controller is as what you've said. My services do all the work. I ask this because i was thinking of separating the class to be modular (file level) and not thinking of the bigger picture (the design).

Comment: Agree with Mark. Comments are part of Post (Core Entity for comment) which can be placed within PostController as it is can be considered as *"Criteria of search"*, at last, its a matter of choice

Answer (score 7):

Here is the skeleton for both the controllers with endpoints, But still you can also have all these endpoints in one controller or different, some people differentiate them based on methods, some based on paths, so i believe this is completely developer experience how to design this

**PostsController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/posts")
public class PostsController {

@PostMapping("/")
public String createPosts() {

    return "createPosts";

}

@GetMapping("/{id}")
public String getPosts(@PathVariable(name = "id") String id) {
    return "getPosts......" + id;
   }

}
```

**CommentsController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/posts/{id}/comments")
public class CommentsController {

@PostMapping
public String createComment(@PathVariable(name = "id") String id) {
    return "createComment..." + id;
}

@GetMapping
public String getComment(@PathVariable(name = "id") String id) {
    return "getComment..." + id;
}

@GetMapping("/{id1@Path}")
public String getCommentById(@PathVariable(name = "id") String id, @PathVariable(name = "id1") String id1) {
    return "getComment..." + id + "...." + id1;
     }

 }
```

Comment: I give this props. However, bottom line is this is a design perspective. As discussed https://stackoverflow.com/a/57238255/1545664. I give props for providing a solution (technical). But i will chose the answer on the design part